# Failed to respond due to okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@9fce4c6

Tags: java, android-studio, okhttp

The error is showing:

> failed to respond due to okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@9fce4c6

This is my code:

```java
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
    if(response.isSuccessful()){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
            String result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
            addResponse(result.trim());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        addResponse("Failed to response due to "+response.body().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.